# complex contour integral with poles

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I really need help with a complex integral.

$\displaystyle{\int_{|{z-1}|=3}\dfrac{dz}{z(z^2-4)e^z}\,dz}$.

This one. Could you please help me and solve this showing me the passages and the result? I should be able to solve this with Cauchy's formula or the residue theorem, but i have problems with poles on the contour, how do I deal with them?

Comment: if this came up in a book/homework, there's certainly an error, because we're not supposed to have poles along the contour of integration. Either they should increase the radius to $r>3$ (strict inequality) or change the $z^2-4$ in the denominator to $z^2-a^2$, for some $-2<a<2$ (for example $z^2-1$), so that there are no poles along the contour.

Comment: Technically, if you have a pole on the contour, the integral diverges, no?

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$f(z) = \frac1{z(z^2 - 4)e^z}$$

be your integrand.

Due to the presence of the pole on the contour, this integral doesn't exist as such, and the conditions of the residue theorem don't apply either. However, around the simple pole at $-2$, the function is antisymmetric to first order and by symmetrically taking a limit as an improper integral, you get the  [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)

$$PV\int_{|z-1| = 3}f(z)dz$$

which is well-defined for this integral. Let's assume this is the integral you want to compute.

Now consider the following closed contour $\Gamma$, made up of a segment $\Gamma_\varepsilon$ equal to your original contour except for a disk of radius $\varepsilon$ around $-2$, and a segment of a circle of radius $\varepsilon$ around $-2$ closing it off:

[image: Closed contour for f(z)]

Then we have

$$PV\int_{|z-1| = 3}f(z)dz = \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{\Gamma_\varepsilon}f(z)dz.$$

The enclosed poles are $0$ and $2$, where the residues are $-\frac14$ and $\frac{e^{-2}}8$, so by the residue theorem we have

$$\int_{\Gamma_\varepsilon}f(z)dz = \int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz - \int_{\gamma_\varepsilon}f(z)dz = 2\pi i\left(\frac{e^{-2}}8 - \frac14\right) - \int_{\gamma_\varepsilon}f(z)dz.$$

In the limit for $\varepsilon\to 0$, the regular part of $f$ doesn't contribute to the integral over $\gamma_\varepsilon$, and since the residue at $-2$ is $\frac{e^2}8$, the integral over the semicircle in the limit is $-\pi i\frac{e^2}8$, the minus sign because it is followed in clockwise direction.

From this we get the value

$$PV\int_{|z-1| = 3}f(z)dz = \pi i\left(\frac{e^{-2}}4 - \frac12 + \frac{e^2}{8}\right).$$

**EDIT**
Let's check this numerically: parameterize the contour as

$$\gamma(\theta) = 3e^{i\theta} + 1.$$

Then

$$PV\int_{|z-1| = 3}f(z)dz = \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{-\pi + \varepsilon}^{\pi - \varepsilon}f(\gamma(\theta))\gamma'(\theta)d\theta.$$

Evaluation using Python with [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/):

```
from mpmath import quad
from cmath import exp, pi

def f(z):
    return 1 / (z * (z**2 - 4) * exp(z))

def g(t):
    return f(3*exp(t * 1j) + 1) * 3j * exp(t * 1j)

def pv(eps):
    return complex(quad(g, [-pi + eps, pi - eps]))

print(pv(1e-6), pi * 1j * (exp(-2)/4 - .5 + exp(2)/8))
```

This outputs

```
1.437168991707318j 1.437171300772436j
```

Comment: Good one, so the actual contour integral doesn't exist, but the improper one does exist! Lessons to be learned for me. The PV , as written in Wikipedia, is the contour integral over $C(\epsilon)$ where $C(\epsilon)$ is the same contour with a ball of radius around $\epsilon$ removed (so it's basically the contour you have, without $\gamma_{\epsilon}$, I think, and therefore isn't closed). But the $\gamma_{\epsilon}$ does seem to contribute, so are we sure that what's been done here matches up with what Wikipedia says? Heart says yes, but head is not convinced.

Comment: Yes, $\gamma_\varepsilon$ *does* contribute, so the integral over the closed contour $\Gamma$ is *not* equal to this principal value. This value can actually be computed, and is the $-\pi i \frac{e^2}8$ that is subtracted at the end. Does that convince you?

Comment: Ah, now it does for sure. You see, I was under the impression that the integral over the closed contour is *defined* as the principal value if there are singularities on the contour, which is why I was a little confused as to whether or not the value specified by you equalled that demanded by OP. Now I'm fully convinced, then I see the code and I read up Python's pv function, so I'm sure I know what is going on. +1 , which I actually gave before my first comment, really nice answer and loved reading it!